# If $g(x,y)=(x+f(y),y+f(x))$ Why this function $g$ is onto?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ of class $C^1$ such that $|f'(x)|\leq b<1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. If we define $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ by $g(x,y)=(x+f(y),y+f(x))$ then why is $g$ an onto function?

*I been trying the following:* since $f$ is of class $C^1$ then $g$ is also of class $C^1$, computing the Jacobian yields $\det(Dg(x,y))=1\cdot 1-f'(y)\cdot f'(x)=1-f'(y)f'(x)\neq 0$ (because $f'(y)f'(x)<1$). Then by the Inverse Theorem $g$ is locally invertible in whole $\mathbb{R}^2$. 
Is that sufficient to conclude $g$ is an onto function?

Also from the hypothesis I know that $f$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition with $b$ constant of Lipschitz.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Use the Banach fixed point theorem to show that , for any $w$, the expression $x+f(y)=w$ has a solution, using the Lipschitz condition. There was a similar problem around recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361257/prove-that-gx-xfx-is-surjective/1361273#1361273) question I solved a very similar problem.

Lets deduce this one from the former:

Define $F(x,y) = (f(y),f(x))$. Then It is clear that it satisfies the condition stated on the link above; moreover, we may see that $g(x,y) = (x,y) + F(x,y)$. The conclusion easily follows from the problem previously solved.

Comment: Thanks! This was very useful!!